# Close Modal in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I just want to know how to close a modal in vue3. I could make it open but I don't know how to close it....

Here my code:

**Search bar**:

```
    <template>
  <div class="search">
    <input placeholder="Search for a recipe" />
    <button @click="showModal = true">Add a new recipe</button>
    <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
      <RecipeForm />
    </modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RecipeForm from "./RecipeForm.vue";
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",
  components: {
    RecipeForm,
  },
  props: {},

  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I have a button on SearchBar component. When I press the button, the modal shows another component that it's call RecipeForm.

When the RecipeForm is opened, it has another button to close it, but I don't know how to do it.

**RecipeForm**

```
<button @click="$emit('close')">
          <img src=@/assets/close-button.svg>
        </button>
```

Where is my error?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Seems like you've a component called `modal` that emits an event named `close`. Could you share the code of `modal` component?

Comment: Sorry...I just emits an event named close cause I saw it in internet but I don't have any modal component. I just have what I post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **RecipeForm** is emitting and you're trying to listen to the emit from **modal** and not from **RecipeForm**.
Move the `@close="showModal = false"` from **modal** component to **RecipeForm**

```js
<template>
  <div class="search">
    <input placeholder="Search for a recipe" />
    <button @click="showModal = true">Add a new recipe</button>
    <modal v-if="showModal">
      <RecipeForm @close="showModal = false" />
    </modal>
  </div>
</template>
```